# WriteFile fails to append but always overwrites

Tags: c++, append, writefile

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("test.txt", FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

ULONG nWritten = 0;
WriteFile(hFile, "line-to-be-appened\r\n", strlen("line-to-be-appened\r\n"), &nWritten, NULL);

CloseFile(hFile);
```

When the above code snippet opens an existing file `test.txt` and is expected to append `"line-to-be-appened\r\n"` to the end of the file.  However, it just overwrites the file.

How can I make it append at the end?

Comment: Just because the file is open with `OPEN_ALWAYS` it doesn't necessarily set the write pointer to the end of the file. Try seeking to the end with `SetFilePointer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are opening the file, its read/write pointer is at the **beginning** of the file by default. Thus, you are writing at the front of the file, overwriting whatever is already there.

To append at the end of the file, you need to seek to the end of the file before writing, either by:

- seeking manually via `SetFilePointer/Ex()`, eg:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("test.txt", FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_END); // <-- add this

ULONG nWritten = 0;
WriteFile(hFile, "line-to-be-appened\r\n", strlen("line-to-be-appened\r\n"), &nWritten, NULL);

CloseFile(hFile);
```

- open the file with just the `FILE_APPEND_DATA` flag by itself, which will then handle the seeking for you, eg:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("test.txt", FILE_APPEND_DATA, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

ULONG nWritten = 0;
WriteFile(hFile, "line-to-be-appened\r\n", strlen("line-to-be-appened\r\n"), &nWritten, NULL);

CloseFile(hFile);
```

`FILE_GENERIC_WRITE` includes both `FILE_WRITE_DATA` and `FILE_APPEND_DATA`, but `FILE_WRITE_DATA` [prevents `FILE_APPEND_DATA` from seeking automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-access-rights-constants):

> For local files, write operations will not overwrite existing data if [FILE_APPEND_DATA] is specified **without FILE_WRITE_DATA**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.
This will  append text in tour file but didn't over write the file.

```
int main()
{
    ofstream hfile;
    hfile.open("test.txt", std::ios_base::app);
    hfile << "line-to-be-appened" << endl;
    hfile.close();
}
```